# hiding stdout with piped mail command

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to hide stdout & stderr from displaying and can't get the syntax right.

I have a one liner in root's .profile to email me whenever there is a root login:

```
netstat -antp | grep ESTABLISHED | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | mail -s "alert: root access on server" email@address.com 2>&1>/dev/null &
```

The problem is that after the mail is sent, I get this on stdout:

```
[1]+  Done  mail -s "alert: root access on server" email@address.com 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

I don't want it to show anything when on the command line when the mail is sent, what am I missing? I also tried this, but no luck:

```
mail -s "alert: root access on server" email@address.com > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I have to have the "&" at the end or it pauses ~30 seconds before login.

Any ideas on how to send the email, hide the stdout and stderr, and run it as a background program?

Thanks!

Comment: See this: http://superuser.com/questions/305933/preventing-bash-from-displaying-done-when-a-background-command-finishes-execut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(netstat -antp | grep ESTABLISHED | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | mail -s "alert: root access on server" email@address.com &)

Comment: sivann, thanks, this works for my needs! one note: it didn't actually surpress all the messages, as i got this from the netstat -antp:
`(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1004 but you should be root.)` 

i knocked out the -p, and things worked great. thanks!